# Nonbreaking space in inline code

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to write a regex, `^ call X *([(&]|$)`, into a README.md but it gets split at the end of a sentence:

some text ... `^ call X`
`*([(&]|$)`

I think it's probably understandable that there is a space between `X` and `*` but it would still be better to display it continuously. Is it possible? It tried `&nbsp;` but it seems not to be working in inline mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must use HTML for this:

```htm
<code>^&nbsp;call&nbsp;X&nbsp;*([(&]|$)</code>
```